# Calling setAttributes() in Gutenberg Block causes bad setState() error in Editor Mode

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-hooks, block, wordpress-gutenberg

In Editor Mode in Wordpress, I see a console error from React when initially rendering my Gutenberg block. Any further changes to the block does not cause the issue.

The exact error is: "Cannot update a component (`EditorProvider`) while rendering a different component (`edit`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `edit`, follow the stack trace".

My original problem was in a function where I retrieved Wordpress User Data and then set it to the attributes. I found out it can occur on a single call though.  Ex: I added the line that causes the issue in the Edit return function:

`setAttributes({userGravatarUrl:'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?d=mp'});`

This is the first time I have attempted to use setAttributes() outside of an onChange property in another component/block.

The attribute name is correct so I know that is not the issue. Is this an error I should ignore? Or how can I remedy this?

My full code below:

```
export default function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes } ) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();
    setAttributes({userGravatarUrl:'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?d=mp'});
    const divStyle = {
        color: attributes.textColor,
        backgroundColor: attributes.backgroundColor,
      };
    return (
        <div { ...blockProps } style={divStyle}>
            <div className='block-section'>
                { attributes.displayGravatar && 
                <img src = {attributes.userGravatarUrl}/>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        );
}
```

block.json

````
        "displayGravatar": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": true
        },
        "displayUserName":{
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": true
        },
        "displayBio":{
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": true
        },
        "selectedUserId":{
            "type": "string"
        },
        "backgroundColor":{
            "type": "string",
            "default": "#FFFFFF"
        },
        "textColor":{
            "type": "string",
            "default": "#000000"
        },
        "userGravatarUrl":{
            "type": "string"
        },
        "userBio":{
            "type": "string"
        },
        "userName":{
            "type": "string"
        }
    }```
````

Comment: I can't see any error in the console. It's working fine.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! Maybe it's just my WP installation, which is a relief.

Comment: @KrunalBhimajiyani While there is no error in the console, this code produces a valid warning; a warning that should be addressed before it causes errors then crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `setAttributes()` in `Edit()` before the return statement causes the "*bad setState()*" call by trying to [set state while rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) another component. While it may seem like a harmless warning and everything appears like its working, many of these bad setState calls eventually leads to performance degradation then app crashes.

To assign a default value to your `userGravatarUrl` attribute inside `Edit()`, update your code to use object [destructing](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6_destructuring.asp) in ES6 on the incoming attributes:

**edit.js**

```jsx
export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    const {
        backgroundColor,
        displayGravatar,
        textColor,
        userGravatarUrl = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?d=mp"
    } = attributes;

    const divStyle = {
        color: textColor,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    };

    return (
        <div {...blockProps} style={divStyle}>
            <div className='block-section'>
                {displayGravatar &&
                    <img src={userGravatarUrl} />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Object destructing can also improve code readability as `attributes.nameOfAttribute` becomes `nameOfAttribute`. By avoiding "bad setState()" calls today, your tomorrow will be easier..

Comment: This is incorrect. The problem "setAttributes() in Edit() before the return statement" is identified well and this is something all WP block builders need to know, however this solution will never update the attribute and therefore will never be passed to the save function to appear on the front end. It will simply provide a 'placeholder' value in the editor view which would be confusing IMO.